# Cannot bind event from Kendo DropDownList generated with ASP.NET MVC helpers to a later defined handler function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my razor view:

```
<div id="divMethod" class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-xs-4">
    <span>Payment Method</span>
</label>
<div class="col-xs-8">
    @(Html.Kendo()
          .DropDownList()
          .Name("typeDropDown")
          .Items(items =>
          {
              items.Add().Text("CreditCard").Value("card");
              items.Add().Text("Electronic Check").Value("bank");
          })
          .Value(Model.DefaultMethod)
          .Events(e => e.Change("selectPaymentMethod")))
</div>
```

(...)

```
<script>
    function selectPaymentMethod() {
        var type = $("#typeDropDown").val();
        if (type === "bank") {
            // Do some stuff here
        }
        else {
            // Do other stuff
        }
    }
</script>
```

This matches the style of all the [examples for this provided by Telerik](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/events). If I load this view as a response to a full-page request, it works fine; but if I load it through an AJAX call inside a Bootstrap modal window, it throws an error when trying to convert the standard input element into the fancy kendo dropdown.
Doing a bit of digging I found that kendo adds this html fragment right after the input:

```
kendo.syncReady(function(){jQuery("#typeDropDown").kendoDropDownList({"change":selectPaymentMethod,"dataSource":[{"Text":"Credit Card","Value":"card"},{"Text":"Electronic Check","Value":"bank"}],"dataTextField":"Text","dataValueField":"Value"});});
```

But it seems that when loaded through AJAX, the kendo.syncReady event gets fired before the browser has finished parsing the entire HTML, so the selectPaymentMethod function doesn't exist yet.

Question: Is there a way to defer the firing of the syncReady function until after the page has finished loading?

Comment: Move the script block containing selectPaymentMethod() above the DropDownList declaration? Or, use .Deferred() on the DropDownList  and call RenderDeferredScripts() at the bottom? https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/fundamentals#configuration-Deferring

Comment: Moving the script block with the function definition to the beginning was the temporary solution I was using, but it seemed kind of dirty to me (I already have other JS code at the bottom so this would mean to have it scattered over several places, which I try to avoid). The Deferred() method from Kendo though is perfect. That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot. You should move your comment to an actual response so I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I don't like making an answer that just points to the documentation without any added value, but thanks.